WebRTC offer/answer handshake with Python does not work
The API I am using requires webRTC for live video streaming (see https://docs.heygen.com/reference/start-session-copy), however the example in their documentation do not work. I am failing to start the webRTC session (I am using Python). I am using Python aiortc to transform the "offer" into an "answer", however I am receiving then always an:
"{'code': 400, 'message': 'peer start failed,please check the answer'}". What I am doing wrong? Also when I do not transform the offer into an answer but just answer the sdp and sdp_type content with the received session_id to the start.session endpoint it is not working. I am completely new to webRTC and have no clue about sdp and all the handshake stuff and also the peer connection which will then be created. Many thanks for your help!!
Below is the code provided:
# Create session
url = "https://api.heygen.com/v1/streaming.new"

payload = { "quality": "medium" }
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-api-key": ";)"
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
response_text = json.loads(response.text)
print(response_text)

sessionID = response_text['data']['session_id']
sdp = response_text['data']['sdp']['sdp']
sdpType = response_text['data']['sdp']['type']
# Type of data we receive
# sessionID = "78afa00e-fbd5-11ee-9d60-faed120e5d26"
# sdp = "v=0\r\no=- 4196988911978866795 1713260476 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 CC:8E:65:72:FF:65:DA:C8:64:CD:B0:70:B7:70:E8:B9:B1:0B:ED:8C:E2:19:ED:A2:D2:AA:17:89:9C:80:4E:DF\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:0\r\na=ice-ufrag:gnfGBmngYiitWqFx\r\na=ice-pwd:qzLzCQBSUMcmchfYQTjcFMkyGReKvEph\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000\r\na=ssrc:1023832023 cname:pion\r\na=ssrc:1023832023 msid:pion video\r\na=ssrc:1023832023 mslabel:pion\r\na=ssrc:1023832023 label:video\r\na=msid:pion video\r\na=sendonly\r\na=candidate:22159748 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.80.3 40289 typ host\r\na=candidate:22159748 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.80.3 40289 typ host\r\na=candidate:233762139 1 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 53354 typ host\r\na=candidate:233762139 2 udp 2130706431 172.17.0.1 53354 typ host\r\na=candidate:778915641 1 udp 1694498815 18.119.137.232 41457 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 41457\r\na=candidate:778915641 2 udp 1694498815 18.119.137.232 41457 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 41457\r\na=candidate:778915641 1 udp 1694498815 18.119.137.232 33272 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 33272\r\na=candidate:778915641 2 udp 1694498815 18.119.137.232 33272 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 33272\r\na=candidate:778915641 1 udp 1694498815 18.119.137.232 57950 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 57950\r\na=candidate:778915641 2 udp 1694498815 18.119.137.232 57950 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 57950\r\na=candidate:778915641 1 udp 1694498815 18.119.137.232 35074 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 35074\r\na=candidate:778915641 2 udp 1694498815 18.119.137.232 35074 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 35074\r\na=candidate:778915641 1 udp 1694498815 18.119.137.232 55550 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 55550\r\na=candidate:778915641 2 udp 1694498815 18.119.137.232 55550 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 55550\r\na=candidate:2563130493 1 udp 16777215 34.203.251.120 59237 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 45975\r\na=candidate:2563130493 2 udp 16777215 34.203.251.120 59237 typ relay raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 45975\r\na=candidate:2563130493 1 udp 16777215 34.203.251.120 59089 typ relay raddr 192.168.80.3 rport 33776\r\na=candidate:2563130493 2 udp 16777215 34.203.251.120 59089 typ relay raddr 192.168.80.3 rport 33776\r\na=candidate:2563130493 1 udp 16777215 34.203.251.120 21402 typ relay raddr 192.168.80.3 rport 51124\r\na=candidate:2563130493 2 udp 16777215 34.203.251.120 21402 typ relay raddr 192.168.80.3 rport 51124\r\na=end-of-candidates\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:1\r\na=ice-ufrag:gnfGBmngYiitWqFx\r\na=ice-pwd:qzLzCQBSUMcmchfYQTjcFMkyGReKvEph\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=ssrc:3859113696 cname:pion\r\na=ssrc:3859113696 msid:pion audio\r\na=ssrc:3859113696 mslabel:pion\r\na=ssrc:3859113696 label:audio\r\na=msid:pion audio\r\na=sendrecv\r\nm=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:2\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\na=ice-ufrag:gnfGBmngYiitWqFx\r\na=ice-pwd:qzLzCQBSUMcmchfYQTjcFMkyGReKvEph\r\n"
# sdpType = "offer"

# ====================================================
# Transform webRTC offer and sdp into answer using aiortc

async def handle_offer(sdp_offer):
    peer_connection = RTCPeerConnection()
    peer_connection.on("track", on_track)

    offer = RTCSessionDescription(sdp_offer, type="offer")
    await peer_connection.setRemoteDescription(offer)

    answer = await peer_connection.createAnswer()
    await peer_connection.setLocalDescription(answer)

    # Signal the answer back (implementation dependent)
    return peer_connection.localDescription.sdp

def on_track(event):
    print("Track received")

sdp = asyncio.run(handle_offer(sdp))
sdpType = "answer"

# ==>
# Start session with transformed answer protocol -> DOES NOT WORK :(
# See: https://docs.heygen.com/reference/start-session-copy
url = "https://api.heygen.com/v1/streaming.start"

payload = {
    "session_id": sessionID,
    "sdp": {
        "type": sdpType,
        "sdp": sdp
    }
}
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-api-key": ";)"
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
response_text = json.loads(response.text)
print(response_text)
# "{'code': 400, 'message': 'peer start failed,please check the answer'}"

